# jQuery autocomplete problems with ajax - TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQueryUI autocomplete function it works fine with data from a local variable but when using data from a $.get request i'm getting the following error: TypeError: this.source is not a function. If I remove $(function(){ in the code there is no error but still no data in autocomplete.

```
Content in: index.html
<script>
$(function(){
var ajaxData;
$.get('ajaxdata.html', function(data) {
$('.result').html(data);
console.log('Load was performed.'+data);
ajaxData = data;
});

var localData = ['ActionScript','AppleScript','Scheme'];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
//source: localData //working
source: ajaxData //not working
});
});
</script>
<input id="tags">

Content in: ajaxdata.html
['ActionScript','AppleScript','Scheme']
```

Comment: move the code for the creation of the autocomplete in the $.get callback function, the reason why it is not working is because an ajax request has an a-synchron, it has a different time scale as the rest of your javascript execution time

Comment: unable to edit my comment- ajax request has an a-synchone time scale :D

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
// use document ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('ajaxdata.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);

    console.log('Load was performed.'+data);

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: data
    });
});
```